# can you overlap partitions when writing parquet files

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, parquet, hadoop-partitioning

I have a very large dataframe around 2TB in size.
There are 2 columns by which I can partition them: `MODULE` and `DATE`
If I partition them by `MODULE` each module can have the same dates for example `MODULE A` might have dates `2020-07-01 , 2020-07-02` and `MODULE B` might have `2020-07-01 , 2020-07-05` etc.
I need to first partition them by `MODULE` and do some aggregations and joins before I finally partition and store them by `DATE`. I am using **pyspark** to code.

After I do the aggregation and joins by MODULE, I am appending it to a parquet file and loading the entire parquet file to a data frame and then partitioning it by DATE.
The problem is that the spark job terminates due to memory issues.
Can I partition by date directly when in `MODULE` partition?
So the partition would look something like this:
Input format: `s3://path/MODULE=A --> s3://path/DATE=2020-07-01` where both modules `A` & `B` are present in partition `DATE=2020-07-01` ?

This was my original code which failed due to very long times in the cluster and running out of memory:

```
inpath="s3://path/file/"
outpath="s3://path/file_tmp.parquet"
fs = s3fs.S3FileSystem(anon=False)
uvaDirs = fs.ls(inpath)

#Load Data by Module
for uvapath in uvaDirs:
    customPath='s3://' + uvapath + '/'
    df1=spark.read.parquet(customPath)
    #Perform aggregations and joins
    df1.write.mode('append').parquet(outpath)
    
# Load - partition by date
df2=spark.read.parquet("s3://path/file_tmp.parquet")
df2.write.mode('overwrite').partitionBy("DATE").parquet("s3://path/final.parquet")
```

It successfully creates the `file_tmp.parquet` but fails when loading and partitioning by date.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

like delta datasource can do this, delta store as parquet

```
(spark.read
 .format("delta")
 .load(path)
 .where(partition)
 .repartition(numFilesPerPartition)
 .write
 .option("dataChange", "false")
 .format("delta")
 .mode("overwrite")
 .option("replaceWhere", partition)
 .save(path))

// clean old file
val deltaTable = DeltaTable.forPath(spark, tablePath)
deltaTable.vacuum(0)
```

refer: https://docs.delta.io/latest/best-practices.html#-delta-compact-files&language-python

Comment: Thank you. That is a nice way to partition randomly to specific size chunks.  But after I save it in delta format, do I need to load the entire parquet again to partition it by date and save it?